# Active Directory Group Inside Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have two group in Active Directory called Group A and Group B. Now Group B is member of Group A. I have added one user in Group A and another user is Group B. I have added Group A in SharePoint site member group. Now if i am log in with user whom i have added in Group A i am able to log in successfully. But if i am login with user whom i have added in Group B. Than it shows that site is not shared with you. As Group B is member of Group A than that user is also able to login. Please guide me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname token-timeout -propertyvalue 1

after that reset iis.

This command has resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that nested AD group is supported for SharePoint 2010/2013, however it is not recommended by some Microsoft groups. I would say don't use AD group nesting.
For more details, please check this blog.
http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2013/04/nested-ad-groups-support-issues-in.html